# How to Port Spring Security XML Config to Java Config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.7 (Spring Security 5.7.6) application with XML configuration for Spring Security.  Eventually I want to get to a Boot 3.x (SS 6.1.0) via the path: Current (SS 5.7.6/XML) -> SS 5.7.6/JavaConfig -> SS 5.8.3 -> SS 6.1.0.  But the first step is not working.

I took my `<http>` elements (there are several) and migrated them to JavaConfig.  I was able to port everything on the elements except I could not find the equivalent of `auto-config=true`. However, when I run the application, there are far fewer servlet filters registered and security is broken (I can access secured URLs anonymously, and `request.getRemoteUser()` always returns null).

I've read [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/configuration/java.html#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) over and over and implemented the changes although I don't understand how they work (`SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and `MvcWebApplicationInitializer` are not Beans, Components, or Configuration), but to no avail. Also, as it's a Boot app, I shouldn't need them, right?

In my Boot application, I already have a `WebMvcConfigurer` subclass and the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.  The `<http>` elements must be doing something else that I can't figure out.

Here is one of the elements that I ported

```
    <http pattern="/service/app/**" once-per-request="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="authDeniedEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="${rememberme.key}"/>
        
        <custom-filter ref="oauth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/app/member/create" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/service/app/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
    </http>
```

which changed to

```
    @Bean
    @Order(100)
    public SecurityFilterChain appFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {       
        http
            .antMatcher("/service/app/**")
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .antMatchers("/service/app/member/create").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/service/app/**").hasRole("MEMBER")
            )
            .addFilterAfter(oauth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter, X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling(handling -> handling.authenticationEntryPoint(authDeniedEntryPoint()))
            .sessionManagement(management -> management
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                    .sessionFixation(c -> c.none()))
            .rememberMe(remember -> remember
                    .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                    .key(rememberMeKey)
                )
            .csrf(c -> c.disable());
        
        return http.build();
    }
```

There is something in the bootstrapping that is not happening, it seems...Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Desperate to make progress, I moved the last couple configuration stanzas out of security.xml and removed it from the @ImportResource annotation. This caused a new error to be thrown on startup.  So first learning is, simply having a security.xml with beans (`http-firewall` and `global-method-security`) apparently cannot co-exist with Java Config.  Second learning, I get the `Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.` because I am still using the old OAuth2 packages (this is one of the things I need to upgrade) that brings in the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

So my conclusion is that my app cannot be converted to Java Config as the first step.  I think the plan must be: SS 5.7.6/XML -> SS 5.8.3/XML -> SS 6.1.0/XML/New OAuth -> SS 6.1.0/Java Config (if I still have the energy after that journey).

**ANOTHER UPDATE** (back to the beginning)

I went through the "get ready for 6.0" for SS 5.8.3 with XML configuration. All my tests are fine, until I get to adding `use-authorization-manager="true"` which turns on [AuthorizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_use_authorizationmanager_for_request_security). The app is completely broken just like it was before with "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" errors everywhere. I used to be able to call `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` and get the username of the authenticated user, but now that method always returns null.  I have `security-context-explicit-save="false"` in case that was preventing populating the SecurityContextHolder.

If I put `use-authorization-manager="true"` on any of my (several) `http` elements in the XML, everything breaks. (this is what was wrong in my initial JavaConfig attempt - I was using `authorizeHttpRequests()` which turns on `AuthorizationManager` and now the app is broken in the same way).

Is there any further advice on how to get the app to work with `AuthorizationManager`?